# When is this multiple integral is finite

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Consider the following integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty du_1 \, du_2 \, du_3 \, e^{-(u_1+u_2+u_3)} \vert u_1-u_2\vert^\alpha \vert u_2-u_3\vert^\alpha\vert u_3-u_1 \vert^\alpha.
$$
The question is to find conditions on  $\alpha$ to assure that the integral is finite.

Comment: And why do you think people should do that for you? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Hint. Consider $\alpha>-1$ and $\alpha\le-1.$

Comment: Why are the $du$'s written before the integrands? That's highly unusual notation.

Comment: @Phys251 This notation is quite common

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you , can you please precise what theorem you use to consider both cases?

Comment: @Phys251 An even better notation with multiple/iterated integrals would be $$\int_0^\infty du_3\,\int_0^\infty du_2\, \int_0^\infty du_1 \, \cdots$$ Of course, it’s the most help when the limits are not the same, and it’s much more helpful than leaving the differentials all the way at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using $a$ for $\alpha,$ we know $a> -1$ is a necessary condition for convergence of the given integral. I think that can be improved to: $a>-2/3$ is a necessary condition.

Let $V=\{(y,z): 0< y < z < 1/2\}.$ Note that $V\times (0,1)$ is a small part of the full domain of integration. Note also that $e^{-(x+y+z)}$ is bounded below by a positive constant on $V\times (0,1).$ Since we'll be integrating over $V\times (0,1),$ we can ignore the exponential. So consider

$$\tag 1 \int_V |z-y|^a\int_0^1 |x-y|^a|z-x|^a\, dx\, dy\, dz.$$

In the inner integral, let $x=y+ (z-y)t.$ That integral becomes

$$|z-y|^{2a+1}\int_{-y/(z-y)}^{(1-y)/(z-y)} |t|^a|1-t|^a\, dx \ge |z-y|^{2a+1}\int_{0}^{1} |t|^a|1-t|^a\, dx.$$

It follows that $(1)$ is at least a constant times

$$\int_V |z-y|^{3a+1}\, dy\, dz = \int_0^{1/2}\int_0^z |z-y|^{3a+1}\, dy\, dz.  $$

The $y$-integral converges iff $3a+ 1> -1$ or $a>-2/3.$ Thus $a>-2/3$ is a necessary condition for convergence of the given integral as claimed.

Comment: Why the condition of convergence on the domain $V \times (0,1)$ is equivalent to the convergence on $(0,\infty)^{3}$ ?

Comment: @nour I didn't say that. I said $a>-2a/3$ is a necessary condition for convergence. I.e, if your integral converges then it must be true that  $a>-2a/3.$ I am far from solving your problem completely.